# How to concat commit messages with GitLab MR squash?

Tags: gitlab

I am using GitLab MR to push commits to my project.
I have a certain template in my commit message that I want to keep on my target branch (e.g. master).
for example:

```
[Notes]:
```

when pushing several commits in a single MR we get something like this:

```
Commit 1:     [Notes]: Note1
Commit 2:     Merge commit (the one I want to get rid of when squashing)
Commit 3:     [Notes]: Note2
```

when squashing with GitLab MR the squashed commit message is the title of the MR, which prevents me to keep my original commits template.

Is there an option in GitLab setting to change the squashed message to be a concat of all commit messages? similar to interactive rebase in git.

wanted behavior:

```
Squashed Commit:    [Notes]: Note1
                    Merge commit (the one I want to get rid of when squashing)
                    [Notes]: Note2
```

`GitLab  14.9.2-ee`

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find what I was looking for, it is a [GitLab feature](http://gitlab-srv/help/user/project/merge_requests/commit_templates.md) introduced in the FREE edition since `GitLab 14.6`.

Open GitLab website -> `Settings` -> `General` -> `Merge requests` -> `Squash commit message template`.

Then in the textbox add the following flag:

```
%{all_commits}
```

The commit messages are shown in the squash message according to their chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

I do have this checkbox (see attached image) in my merge request enabling me to change the Merge Commit Message but I am using: `15.2.1-ee` I'm not sure on what version this got introduced. I think there was a similar functionality in previous versions. [image]

Comment: Thanks for checking it for me buddy!
I don't have this checkbox in my version. Once I check `Squash commits` I have the `modify commit message` blue line that lets me edit the message.
But I want it to be a copy of all the previous commits.. and copying them from `commits` tab is inconvenient since you have to open them 1 by one and copy.. 
btw, I use the `free` (but standalone) version, which version do you use?